# General Binary Data Viewer for Windows Vista

Tags: file-format, devtools, hex-editors

I'm looking for recommendations for a good program for 32-bit Windows Vista that will load any arbitrary binary file and display textual information or graphical visualization relevant to identifying what actual data the bits are supposed to represent. Is ther anything better than a [hex editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer#10431) for this kind of thing?

One thing I'd like to do is say, look at the non-visible data in a [Spore](http://www.spore.com) PNG file to get a clue as to what's actually being stored in there. Right now I'm using WordPad and all I get is something that looks like this:

> ‰PNG
>
> IHDR ¢
>
> /Qã!$D4"Ž‚îvÚ°‰ÅØÃ ïjÃÞÉ_{!…‡ú 9¥Ý´îÁ6 ‰ms ^

I guess what I'm looking for is a souped up hex editor that acts more like an Excel for bits so I can slice and dice statistical patterns to get a better idea of what the bits might be doing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/):

> HxD is a carefully designed and fast
>   hex editor which, additionally to raw
>   disk editing and modifying of main
>   memory (RAM), handles files of any
>   size.
>
> The easy to use interface offers
>   features such as searching and
>   replacing, exporting,
>   checksums/digests, insertion of byte
>   patterns, a file shredder,
>   concatenation or splitting of files,
>   statistics and much more.

[image]

Comment: HxD doesn't show binary `0` and `1`s. It only shows in hexadecimal/octal.

Answer (score 7):

I like [xvi32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm), although it seems similar to the above - I've found it to be fairly fast even for big files.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is a hex editor. The [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) text editor has a pretty good hex-editing mode.

Answer (score 1):

I use [HHD's free HexEditor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Family/hex-editor.html), it's Free!

Answer (score 0):

I use frhed and vim (with its convert to hex mode but that can be slow for big files).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something that detects a set of known fileformats and knows how to display them? Otherwise, hex editor (for example [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) contains one) is the best thing that you can wish for. It's just bits which can mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Total Commander's](http://www.ghisler.com) built-in Lister (file viewer). It can show data as text, hex, it can show images. Then there are many plugins that range from code editors / viewers, image viewers etc.

Plugins I use are

- imagine for viewing images
- fileinfo for displaying info of executables
- HTML viewer
- Syn2 - code viewer / editor with syntax highlighting

There are a lot of plugins listed on author's web page, another good source is [www.totalcmd.net](http://www.totalcmd.net)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Hex Workshop](http://www.hexworkshop.com/) before, it has a "Find Strings" option in the Tools menu. Not free but works great.